# Disable mail functions in php BY .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to disable mail functions in PHP by .htaccess throw-out my all project file. I need to do stop all e-mail that send by system in my project so there are many files that use `mail()` function in my project so there is way to `disable mail functions` ? I can't access `php.ini` so it better to do with `.htaccess`

in `.htaccess` i write this code but not work:

```
  php_value  disable_functions  mail
```

this is not worked but any other way to disable mail function by `.htaccess` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`PHP configuration directive` definition in `.htaccess` depends on `server configuration`. It can be disable on your `webserver`. You can put `php.ini` in your site root and put this directive. Alternatively, you can set this directive on application runtime by

```
ini_set('disable_functions','mail');
```

Answer (score 2):

disable_functions only can modificate in php.ini:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions